# how to write 1 function insteaed of n functions to validate textboxes requiring same validations?

Tags: javascript

This is my sample code in which i have 2 text boxes requiring same validations.How can i write a single function for both the text boxes requiring same validations. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Home</title>

<body style="background-color:#708090;">

<script type="text/javascript" >


function a() {
    var ay = document.getElementById("ayear").value;

var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{2,4}/;


    if(pattern.test(ay))

    {

    ay.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
    return true;
        } 
    else 
    {
        window.alert ("Enter the correct acadamic year");
    ay.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
     ay.focus();
         ay.value="";        
     return false;

    }
}


function b() {

var fy=document.getElementById("fyear").value;
var fpattern = /\d{4}-\d{2,4}/;


  if(fpattern.test(fy))
    {

    fy.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
    return true;
        } 
    else 
    {
        window.alert ("Enter the correct financial year");
    fy.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
        fy.focus();
        fy.value="";
    return false;

    }
}

function c()
{


    var n=document.getElementById("name");

    var re=/^[a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]*$/;

    if(re.test(n.value))
    {

               n.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("Invalid place name");
               n.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
               n.focus();
               n.value="";

    }
}


</script>





</p>
<h3 style="font-family:Verdana">Notes</h3>

<h4 "style="font-family:Verdana;text-align:center;"><b><u>Declaration</u></b></h4>

<form   method="post">

<p> This  Report is prepared for the Current Acadamic Year(<input type="text" size="9"  id="ayear" onchange=a();>) and the Current Financial Year (<input type="text" size="9"  id="fyear" onchange=b();>) on behalf of the Institution.</p>




</form>

</body>
</html>
```

`

In the code function a and b does same validations so can i reduce 2 functions to 1? please help me I'm a fresher need to do a bigger logic later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass id as an argument, so that it will work for both cases

```
function a(idname) {
    var ay = document.getElementById(idname).value;
    var element = document.getElementById(idname);//added object
    var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{2,4}/;

    if(pattern.test(ay)) {
       element.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
       return true;
    } else {

     window.alert ("Enter the correct acadamic year");
     element.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
     element.focus();
     element.value="";        
     return false;

     }
}
```

For above function to work you need to make following changes in your form

```
<form   method="post"> 
     <input type="text" size="9"  id="ayear" onchange="a('ayear');">
     <input type="text" size="9"  id="fyear" onchange="a('fyear');">
   </form>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pScMk/)

Comment: did u mean' (<input type="text" size="9"  id="fyear" onchange="a('fyear');">)' instead of this '(<input type="text" size="9"  id="fyear" onchange="b('fyear');">)'?

Comment: @suhas yes you are calling the same function, just passing different arguments

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question and you should be glad it worried you enough to ask :)

In order to reduce code duplication, not just in javascript, you should always ask yourself what can be generic. In this case, you can simply pass the parameter which indicates which object to validate.

For example:

```
    function a(elementId) {
        var ay = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
...
}
```

and then you'd be able to call a("ayear") and a("fyear").

Good luck!

Comment: can you edit the code which i had sent and send me because, i had tried exactly as you said before but it did'nt work. Im working on javascript since only a week

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<input type="text" size="9"  id="ayear" onchange="a(this);" >
```

and then change the function like

```
function a(elem) {

var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{2,4}/;


    if(pattern.test(elem))

    {

    elem.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
    return true;
        } 
    else 
    {
        window.alert ("Enter the correct acadamic year");
    elem.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
     elem.focus();
         elem.value="";        
     return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More configurable version

```
function validator(obj, pattern, info, bgc, bgc2) {

  if(pattern.test(obj.value))
  {
    obj.style.backgroundColor=bgc;
    return true;
  } 
  else 
  {
    window.alert (info);
    obj.style.backgroundColor=bgc2;
    obj.focus();
    obj.value="";        
    return false;
  }
}
```

And in html onchange() call fn validator with parameters:

```
<form method="post"> 
 <input type="text" size="9"  id="ayear" onchange="validator(this, /\d{4}-\d{2,4}/, 'Enter the correct acadamic year', '#52F40C', '#F40C0C');">
 ......
</form>
```